# No boundaries snake game

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic, 2d-games

I am trying to adapt this snake game: http://jsfiddle.net/unsign3d/uq6YL/ to have a "scrolling grid" in the sense that the snake will be able to travel off any side of the grid and will appear on the other side. An example of this sort of snake game can be found here: http://codeincomplete.com/projects/snakes/. I am sure that the solution is a simple one but unfortunately it is conceptually and syntactically out of my grasp.

This is the code that detects collision:

```
function check_collision(x, y, array) {
    //This function will check if the provided x/y coordinates exist
    //in an array of cells or not
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].x == x && array[i].y == y) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think using a circular buffer here might be useful but I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code part checks the snake hited the boundary or not. He will be keeping array of bricks where snakes x,y shoudn't reach(If hits "game over"). In each intervel the thread which runs the snake will update its position. The new position will be passing as x & y. If it is any where in the border cells(array) the funtion will return you true means it hit on the boudary. Other wise false

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about this for a minute. In the original version of the game, if the snake travels off the board, the game is over. How do we implement that? Since we're working with a rectangular grid, we know the coordinates of the edges of the board. If the snake's head goes outside of these ranges, the game ends.

[image: Simple snake board]

In the example above, the snake can't travel to (-50, -50), because that isn't a valid position on the board. So as the snake moves, we need to check that it's next 'x' and 'y' position is valid.  If that 'x' is below 0 or above 100, or if  that 'y' is below 0 or above 200, the snake can't move there. In the regular version of the game, the game would end.

Once you get that working, you can implement the wrap-around style border with just a few changes. First you'll need to determine the coordinates of the border and draw it on the board. Now you'll have your new 'off-limits' coordinates. But instead of ending the game when the snake goes beyond those bounds, you'll just need to change the snake's 'x' or 'y' coordinates.

[image: Wrap-around snake board]

For example, let's say the snake is traveling to the right. When he hits the border, his 'x' position will be at 95. When that happens, we'll change that to 5 to make him appear on the left side of the screen. Similarly, if the snake is traveling upwards and hits the border, his 'y' position will be 5. To make him appear on the bottom of the screen, we just need to change that position to 195.

Answer (score 0):

Just modulo the coordinates with the maximum window coordinates.